# Run service using cron job on CentOS 7

Tags: linux, centos, cron, centos7

I want to run **apollo-broker-service** service using **cron job on CentOS 7**.
For this I am created a file **/home/guest/start_apollo** mentioned below

```
#!/bin/bash

if pidof -x "apollo" >/dev/null; then
echo "Apollo MQTT is Running."
else
echo "Apollo MQTT is Stopped."
service apollo-broker-service start
fi
```

I am login with ssh root and run following command

```
cd /home/guest/
chown root start_apollo
chgrp -R root start_apollo
chmod +x start_apollo
```

I want to run **/home/nagios/start_apollo every 1 minute** For this I added the following line into **/etc/crontab**

```
01 * * * * root /home/nagios/start_apollo > /var/log/start_apollo_service.log
```

I created a **/var/log/start_apollo_service.log** with following permission

```
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root   root         0 Aug 11 20:08 start_apollo_service.log
```

then **restart crond service** using below command

```
systemctl restart crond.service
```

After all this my cron job not working and there is no log created on /var/log/start_apollo_service.log

Answer (score 2):

I believe that your cronjob is not set to run every 1 minute but once every hour at the minute 1.

Try this first, and then change it if you really meant once every hour at minute 01:

```
* * * * * root /home/nagios/start_apollo > /var/log/start_apollo_service.log
```

Comment: When i try "*/1 * * * * root /home/nagios/start_apollo > /var/log/start_apollo_service.log" my cron job run apollo service every 1 minute successfully.
I have another service "nohup node /root/code/demo-project/index.js > /root/index.js &" when i try to run this using cron job it is not running. Can you help me?

Comment: I think that the nohup and the & are out of place. These are only necessary to "daemonize" scripts, which cron is already doing for you. This could be another question. By the way... you could up-vote my answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

I resolved my issue by using the following

```
*/1 * * * * root /home/nagios/start_apollo > /var/log/start_apollo_service.log
```